# Are there Virtual Machines that allow lots of VRAM allocation?

Tags: virtualbox, virtualization

I'm interested in running Fusion 360 and set up a virtual machine to do this effectively. However, VirtualBox caps out at vRAM 256MB which hinders the performance of Fusion, and I was wondering if there are other VMs that offer higher vRAM capacities.

Comment: Yes there are (with TB limits), but you've not provided any OS & release details, as product & release can impact the limits allowed.

Comment: Would [installation via Wine](https://github.com/cryinkfly/Autodesk-Fusion-360-for-Linux) be an option? This gets around the various limits imposed by a VM 

Comment: There is [an online version of Fusion 360](https://fusion.online.autodesk.com/?_ga=2.66130023.893281974.1637176636-1209008280.1631829953) which might work. There is also [a snap version](https://snapcraft.io/fusion360). Check those out, and see if either of those would work, as they would be easier than using a VM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all your advice. I decided to go with [matigo's](https://askubuntu.com/users/1222991/matigo) suggestion as it was a very straightforward installation process. I've chosen to run Fusion natively as opposed to on a VM to get around the limitations set by virtualization.